# When will I get my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I answered some questions on Stack Overflow and got some votes. But my reputation is not increased. What is this? If there is a time to count this then what is the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the questions weren't Community-Wiki posts, which award no reputation due to their nature.

Comment: hmmmmmm. This is the reason. Ok

Comment: ...other questions require 6-8 weeks.  jk.  ;-)